# SIGPIPE in a simple two process program

Tags: c, pipe, fork, sigpipe

I have a simple setup for a fork and pipe that I have used before. But this time around I'm getting a `SIGPIPE` in my `write` call. Here's the code

```
int fd[2];

int pid;

if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
    perror("pipe init error"); 
    exit(1);
}


// signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
if ((pid = fork()) < -1) {
    perror("fork error"); exit(1);
}
// parent
else if (pid > 0) {
    close(fd[0]); 

    write(fd[1], "WHAT", MAXWORD); //SIGPIPE here

    close(fd[1]);
    int status;
    wait(&status);
}

// child
else {
    close(fd[1]);
    // void foo(char *dirname, int in, int out);
    // foo takes a path, reads from fd 'in' and outputs to 'fd' out
    foo("./some/path", fd[0], 1);
    close(fd[0]);
}
```

Here's function foo:

```
void foo(char *dirname, int in, int out){

    int string_length;
    char word[MAXWORD];

    // to get rid of \n
    char* sep;
    sep = malloc(sizeof(char));


    // read from piped stdin until it's closed
    while ((string_length = read(in, word, MAXWORD)) > 0){

        // get rid of \n
        sep = strchr(word, '\n');
        *sep = '\0';

        printf("THe word is: %s\n", word);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get SIGPIPE when you write on a pipe, it means there is no process that can read from the pipe: neither the current process (you've close the read end of the pipe — which is good; you'd be deadlocked instead of dead if you'd not closed it) nor the other (child) process.

Since you've not shown what the function `foo()` does, we can't tell you any more about what's wrong.

---

Now that `foo()` has been added, it is not clear what's up.  There are issues, but most are not show stoppers.

1. Argument `dirname` is unused.
2. Argument `out` is unused.
3. You leak the memory allocated to `sep` in the loop.
4. You do not ensure that the string read from the pipe is null terminated.  This could lead to crashes, which in turn would lead to writes failing.

I suspect item 4 is the immediately critical issue; the others are more matters of tidiness.

I note that in the main code, you have:

```
write(fd[1], "WHAT", MAXWORD); //SIGPIPE here
```

Unless `MAXWORD` is either 4 or 5, you are on a losing path; you should only write 4 or 5 characters.

Combined with the `read()`...the read will attempt to read MAXWORD bytes but might get fewer.  However, there's no sign that the data written contains a newline, so the search for a newline in the input is not going to work reliably.  However, that problem should manifest itself after the pipe was successfully written too, not before.

I note that the variable `int fd_parent_write_word[2];` is unused and the code uses variable `int fd[2]` without declaring it.

It is a nuisance when what you get to analyze is not an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  It is so much easier when the test case has been reduced to a simple program that can be compiled and run with the submitter confident that the problem reproduces with it.

---

This SSCCE code compiles cleanly and runs OK:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum { MAXWORD = 5 };

static void foo(int in);

static void he_who_pays_the_piper(int signum)
{
    assert(signum == SIGPIPE);
    const char msg[] = "Received signal SIGPIPE\n";
    write(2, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    int pid;

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe init error"); 
        exit(1);
    }

    signal(SIGPIPE, he_who_pays_the_piper);
    if ((pid = fork()) < -1) {
        perror("fork error"); exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {
        close(fd[0]); 
        write(fd[1], "WHAT", MAXWORD); //SIGPIPE here
        close(fd[1]);
        int status;
        pid = wait(&status);
        printf("Got status 0x%04X from %d\n", status, pid);
    }
    else {
        close(fd[1]);
        foo(fd[0]);
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}


static void foo(int in)
{
    int string_length;
    char word[MAXWORD];

    while ((string_length = read(in, word, MAXWORD)) > 0)
        printf("The word is: %.*s\n", string_length, word);
}
```

Example output:

```
The word is: WHAT
Got status 0x0000 from 49458
```

Note that this works because the `'\0'` at the end of the string `WHAT` is written to the pipe, and read from the pipe.  Most usually, you do not write the strings including the trailing `'\0'`.